# Ошибка about:blank#blocked при переходе через php?

Tags: php, html

Имеется login.php и в нем код на подключение и передача id пользователя на другую страницу.
По идее она должна открываться в новом окне с url: wow.php?id=1. Но вместо этого я могу открыть его только через консоль разработчика и когда я это делаю он выводит мне about:blank#blocked. В чем может быть проблема?

код login.php:

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '0000', 'cars');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,login, password FROM authorized WHERE login='$login' AND password='$pass'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $page = "<a href='./wow.php/".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
    echo $page;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Похоже проблема в наcтройках безопаcноcти...браузера и/или антивируcа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Ваш формат ссылки:

```
<a href='./wow.php/".$id."'>".$id."</a>
```

Мало того что точка перед /wow как будто абсолютный путь от текущей папки указывает, но Вы так же пишете что открываться надо в новом окне с GET параметром id, но у Вас сделано совершенно не так.

Попробуйте такой формат ссылки:

```
<a href='/wow.php?id=".$id."'>".$id."</a>
```